# Show that an element of the factor group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order if and only if it is in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Show that an element of the factor group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order if and only if it is in  $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

**What I have done**: So far I know that if $a$ is an element in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, then $a$ has the form $\frac{b}{c}+\mathbb{Z}$, with $b,c \in \mathbb{Z},c\neq0$. Without loss of generality suppose that $c>0$, then $ca=c\left ( \frac{b}{c}+\mathbb{Z} \right )=b+\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$ wich is the identity element in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Thus $ a$ has finite order. I think this part proves ($\leftarrow $)

I have trouble establishing the other implication and verifying the theorem. I mean...

> If an element of the factor group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order, then this element lies in   $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: suppose $x+\mathbb{Z}$ has finite order where $x\in\mathbb{R}$. That means that $nx\in\mathbb{Z}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: If $nx \notin \mathbb{Z}$, then $x\neq \frac{m}{n}$, so $x+\mathbb{Z}$ has infinite order?

Comment: Yes, although you can do it directly as well. $nx = m\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $x=$?

Comment: $x=\frac{m}{n}\in \mathbb{Q}$